# Update deployment from within Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, permissions

I am attempting to use the k8s API inside the cluster to update a deployment within the namespace home.

ClusterRole:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: home
  name: home-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods, deployments"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list", "create", "delete", "update"]
```

Service Account:

```
get serviceaccounts -n home
NAME      SECRETS   AGE
default   1         3h2m
kubectl describe serviceaccounts -n home          
Name:                default
Namespace:           home
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   default-token-8rzns
Tokens:              default-token-8rzns
Events:              <none>
```

ClusterRoleBinding:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding home-role-binding \
 --clusterrole=home-role  \
 --serviceaccount=home:default
```

But I am getting this error when the API call is made:

```
open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
```

Does anyone have any insight into where the issue may lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off deployments are in apps/v1, not v1.  Then you probably need to share the pod definition for the place you are running your api call from. You may have disabled service account token mounting.

Comment: "spec: automountServiceAccountToken: false"
You're onto something here, thanks. Ill update you when I get there.

Comment: "You may have disabled service account token mounting."
...
      spec {
        restart_policy = "Always"
        automount_service_account_token = true
        container {
...

Solved the secrets problem. Next is the API path. Thanks